# trying to write server with boost::asio async read and write simultaneously

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I narrow the problem to the part of getting the data from the message_queue and writing it to the TCP connection. the thread is blocked on the `async_read` and it can not read from the message queue. is there a way to solve it?

I have a client-server application that the server is actually a pipe between two machines,
the flow is like that: phase 1 and 4 are via TCP and 2 and 3 are via `boost::interprocess::message_queue` the client can send a request with no need to write for a response from the server

```
--------     1       --------    2         --------
|      | request     |      | request    |      |
| main | ------>     |server|  ------>   |client|
|client|  response 4 |      |  response 3|      |
|      | <------     |      |  <------   |      |
--------             --------            --------
```

the problem is that my server gets stuck on `boost::asio::async_read` after he gets the request and he is not "waking up" when he is read to do, I'm guessing that maybe I need to read another thread just for the read?.
this is the message class:

```
class Message
{
 public:
  enum { header_length = 5 };
  enum { max_body_length = 512 };

  Message()
      : body_length_(0) { }

  const char* data() const {
    return data_;
  }

  char* data() {
    return data_;
  }

  std::size_t length() const {
    return header_length + body_length_;
  }

  const char* body() const {
    return data_ + header_length;
  }

  char* body() {
    return data_ + header_length;
  }

  std::size_t body_length() const {
    return body_length_;
  }

  void body_length(std::size_t new_length) {
    body_length_ = new_length;
    if (body_length_ > max_body_length)
      body_length_ = max_body_length;
  }

  bool decode_header() {
    char header[header_length + 1] = "";
    std::strncat(header, data_, header_length);
    body_length_ = std::atoi(header);
    if (body_length_ > max_body_length) {
      body_length_ = 0;
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  void encode_header() {
    char header[header_length + 1] = "";
    std::sprintf(header, "%4d", static_cast<int>(body_length_));
    std::memcpy(data_, header, header_length);
  }

 private:
  char data_[header_length + max_body_length];
  std::size_t body_length_;
};
```

this is the server code:

```
namespace {
  using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
  auto constexpr log_active=true;

};

class Session
    : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Session>
{
 public:
  Session(tcp::socket socket)
      : socket_(std::move(socket)) ,
      response_queue_(boost::interprocess::open_or_create, "response_queue", 100, 100),
      request_queue_(boost::interprocess::open_or_create, "request_queue", 100, 100),
  {
  }

  void start()
  {
      post(strand_, [this, self = shared_from_this()] {
          do_write();
          do_read_header();
      });
  }


 private:
  void do_read_header()
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    std::cout << "do_read_header\n";    
    boost::asio::async_read(socket_,  //<-- get stuck here
                            boost::asio::buffer(res.data(), res.header_length),
                            [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
                            {
                              if (!ec && res.decode_header())
                              {
                                do_read_body();
                              }
                            do_read_header();
                            });
  }

  void do_read_body() {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    Message msg;
    std::cout << "do_read_body\n";
    boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(res.body(), res.body_length()),
                            [this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length) {
                              if (!length) {
                                return;
                              }
                              if (!ec) {
                                if constexpr (log_active) {
                                  request_log << "read " << res.body() << "\n";
                                  request_log.flush();
                                }
                                std::cout << "read " << res.body() << "\n";
                                request_queue_.send(res.body(), res.body_length(), 0);
                              } else {
                                if (ec) {
                                  std::cerr << "read error:" << ec.value() << " message: "
                                            << ec.message() << "\n";
                                }
                                socket_.close();
                              }
                            });

  }

  void do_write()
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    Message msg;

    boost::interprocess::message_queue::size_type recvd_size;
    unsigned int priority = 0;

    bool res = response_queue_.try_receive(msg.body(),msg.max_body_length,recvd_size,priority);
    if(!res)
      return;
    try {
      msg.body_length(recvd_size);
      msg.encode_header();
      std::memcpy(data_,msg.data(), msg.length());
    } catch (std::exception& e )
    {
      std::cout << e.what();
    }
   
    std::cout << "write " << msg.body() << "\n";
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(data_,msg.length()),
                             [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
                             {
                               if (ec)
                               {
                                 std::cerr << "write error:" << ec.value() << " message: " << ec.message() << "\n";
                               }
                               std::cout << "num message in queue " << response_queue_.get_num_msg() << "\n";
                               while(response_queue_.get_num_msg())
                               {
                                 do_write();
                               }
                             });
  }
  using Executor = boost::asio::system_executor;
  boost::asio::strand<Executor> strand_ { Executor{} };
  tcp::socket socket_ { strand_ };
  enum { max_length = 1024 };
  char data_[max_length];
  Message res;
  boost::interprocess::message_queue response_queue_;
  boost::interprocess::message_queue request_queue_;

};
```

Comment: doesn't your recursion of `do_read_header` need to be at the end of the callback in `do_read_body` not in `do_read_header`? Otherwise you have concurrent calls to `async_read` on a single socket which is undefined behaviour

Comment: @AlanBirtles still not working

Comment: @AlanBirtles I update the question because I narrow the problem.